# Does azure synapse serverless sql pool database support Query store?

Tags: sql, serverless, azure-synapse

Tried turning on Query store on a Serverless SQL pool database in Synapse workspace, but it is throwing error "QUERY_STORE is not supported for ALTER DATABASE."

[image]

I expect Query store to be available for serveless sql pool database , but can't make this to work

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't support query store (or a large number of related features such as user visible execution plans).

It does have a DMV `sys.dm_exec_requests_history` with a log of historic queries and a few stats about them though.

Comment: Is there a MS doc/blog/post where this is clearly indicated ? Also the DMV sys.dm_exec_requests_history does not have the exact query text which was executed, How can we get it ? Thanks!

Comment: "Applies to:  SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and later  Azure SQL Database  Azure SQL Managed Instance  Azure Synapse Analytics (**dedicated SQL pool only**)"  -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: And I haven't seen the issue with it not showing the exact query text. How do you mean? - Though chances are you will be out of luck anyway. You likely need to recalibrate your expectations about SQL Serverless as the information it makes available is extremely basic and limited